# errbot error with help command

Tags: python, errbot

So I just installed Errbot.

I run it and get this when running !help

```
 >>> !help
 Computer says nooo. See logs for details:
 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2022' in position 75: ordinal not     in range(128)
```

Any advice on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure that your system is configured for UTF-8.

If you run under Linux for example, try the command `locale` to check your current encoding.